# Naive senior moment from an ios rookie - IAP

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm at a bit at a loss (both in terms of the correct home for this question/advice and as to whether it's possible). We have our 1st app just approved in the appstore this week and had imagined that we could use the promo codes to allow reviewers to unlock the IAP's. This of course is not possible as we now appreciate that the promo codes literally give access to the physical download of the app itself (and not any virtual properties wrapped inside the app).

Therefore, I'm wondering, just what are the options available to allow us to present bloggers and reviewers with a fully functioning version. With the presence of hindsight, I should have of course created a version that had the IAP options all included and priced it so that a promo code could cover it - such is life. So, are there any 3rd party services (other than Testflight) that would allow for ad-hoc distribution at short notice for this purpose, without the end user having to go thro too many hoops??

Comment: Give the reviewers an iTunes credit for the purchase? You can buy iTunes credit codes and email them. It means they get it for free, you end up handing 30% to Apple; but how much is your time worth?

Comment: @jim tollan, I generally just gift the app to them so they can get the first hand opinion. Although I am paying for the app I gifted but in the long run its worth it because of the exposure I get through their writings. But that's just me.:)

Comment: hi floris and code monkey -i had looked at the gift certificate option, but could only see values starting at $15. we are talking about 50+ reviewers, so obviously, looking for best bang for buck. i agree on what is your time worth and definitely want to take the path of least resistence. does the credit codes cover the eventualities of Band 3 IAP etc (i.e. a $3.99 credit code), as well as paid for apps?? if so, is the way to go for sure.